# Use variable for the port in the "Wait for http port" Action

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to use a variable for the port in the "Wait for http port" Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 5.1.x, this is not possible. You change it with a code snippet, though. Add a "Run script" action with the script

```
import com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.*;

int port = (Integer)context.getVariable("myPort");
((WaitForHttpPortAction)context.getActionById("123")).setPort(port);

return true;
```

This assumes that you have saved an integer port value to the installer variable "myPort". You have to replace "123" with the actual ID of the "Wait for http port" action.